# How to release memory in Android?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I want to know how to release memory in Android programmatically, because my layout contains a lot of views and when I go to any Activity the app stops working and gives me an out of memory error.

```
So what is the way to release Memory  ?
```

Comment: The answer you have accepted is down voted for a good reason, it is a terrible practice. Hard to say where your memory problem comes from without seeing the code, but Mehul Patel's answer is a good start for diagnosis. You should not resort to hacks to manage memory, but instead refactor your code to make it more memory efficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use this onBackPressed event, and it totally release my app process:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

You cant just release memory it is the garbage collectors jobs to find the reference of this object if the object is not used then garbage collector kicks in.

The problem is that you have a `lots of nested View` which consumes a lot of memory, you can either minimized your views to use less memory space in the heap or dynamically add the view when you need it and remove other views when you dont need it to save memory space.

Comment: isn't there a way to do it when i go to an other page or press the back button.

Comment: @user3896367 as I said minimized the use of views in one layout to avoid Out Of Memory.

Comment: @user3896367 it happened when you are changing activities or restarting the activity. To learn more go here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: @user3896367 forced garbage collection is forbidden!